# I would like to retrieve data from a MySQL database using PHP using HTTP requests, on my Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

Please help me find a way to do it.

I have looked at the following for sending data [Arduino to MySql](http://www.instructables.com/id/PART-1-Send-Arduino-data-to-the-Web-PHP-MySQL-D3js/)

But can't seem to find visa-versa.

Comment: What actions have you taken yet? What does/doesn't work?
Is the connection between arduino/php website working or is the problem at php<-mysql

Comment: Sure, why not. If interested let us know a time frame, any of us here would deliver you the way, and quote you accordingly.

Comment: Point is that i forgot to check the date of the question, :D replied to a 2yr old question.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you have to set up for this:
1. Retrieving/parsing websites from your Arduino.
2. Making a dynamic website using PHP (and MySql).

- Try to set up your Arduino as a [WebClient](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient), check if you can retrieve a website like google.com or [a minimalistic website](http://www.minimalsites.com/).
- Try to get your arduino to interpret a string or retrieve values from that website. (I.E: retrieve the day/time from the HTTP message)

IF your arduino can retrieve webpages, you're halfway there (somewhat). And your project is running out of the scope of this arduino.stackexchange.

Now you're going to have to [create a dynamic website](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=dynamic%20website%20php%20mysql&es_th=1). You can let PHP reach for values from your MySql database (you should just use a text file first) and display them on your site (in HTML).
Your Arduino can now poll your website, to get the HTML content and parse it to the values.

Answer (score 2):

You could develop a REST based service, to make Arduino consume web service using the [aRest](https://github.com/marcoschwartz/aREST) library.

Following is a tutorial of how to use the aRest API with Arduino: [A REST API for Arduino & the CC3000 WiFi Chip](https://learn.adafruit.com/a-rest-api-for-arduino-and-the-cc3000-wifi-chip?view=all).